# Python XGBoost killing kernel

Tags: python, xgboost

My Jupyter notebook's python kernel keeps dying when attempting to train an XGBoost logistic classifier. Previously, I have run all of the following code successfully. Presently, there are issues. First, I will show you the code chunk that I am able to run successfully:

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data = X_train_sub.values, label = Y_train.values)       # create dense matrix of training values
xgtest  = xgb.DMatrix(data = X_test_sub.values,  label = Y_test.values)        # create dense matrix of test values
param   = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}  # specify parameters via map
```

where my data is small:

```
X_train_imp_sub.shape
(1365, 18)
```

however, my notebook's kernel keeps dying on this chunk:

```
xgmodel = xgb.train(param,  xgtrain, num_boost_round = 2)                      # train the model
predictions = xgmodel.predict(xgtest)                                          # make prediction
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score                                   
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true = Y_test, 
                          y_pred = predictions.round(), 
                          normalize = True) # If False, return # of correctly classified samples. Else, return fraction of correctly classified samples
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

As stated before, I have been able to run both chunks successfully before. I have shut down all other notebooks and restarted my computer without luck. I am launching `jupyter` through Anaconda Navigator on a Macbook Pro.

---

UPDATE:

To further debug, I used Terminal CLI and ran:

1. conda install runipy
2. runipy MyNotebook.ipynb

which was very helpful, because it produced the following error message that I could then Google:

```
OMP: Error #15: Initializing libomp.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized.
OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For more information, please see http://openmp.llvm.org/
```

I found this thread:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1715

Which shows others having the same problem on MacOS. I also suspected the problem being linked to `matplotlib` somehow because running any cell with  `matplotlib` related code somehow causes the `xgb.train` to kill the kernel.

Comment: What is the shape of `xgtrain`? It might be possible that python is running out of memory.

Comment: What are your machine specs... It's actually weird as you can't run out of memory with such a small dataset... I guess the error is somewhere else.. You have tried restarting the kernel also, so another option to try it out is run it in raw python as a script and report back...

Comment: @AnkitSeth not sure how to find the shape of an `xgb.DMatrix`.

Comment: @Aditya it's a new Macbook Pro so should be pretty powerful. Yes, I have restarted the kernel probably a few dozen times trying to fix the problem.

Comment: You can try downgrading the version of xgboost to 0.80

Answer (score 3):

When I selected a cell beneath my `xgboost` training cell, then selected: `Cells` --> `Run All Above`, the kernel would always die on the `xgboost` training cell. This happened probably 40-50 times in a row.

When I ran the same cells one-by-one, it completed fine on the first time I tried this and every time after.

Comment: Now this is really weird, try running your whole code in a .py file directly via ` python filename.py`

Comment: @Aditya yeah. good idea. i updated my original post w/ more info and what i found as a result of your suggestion.

Comment: Pardon me I ain't a MAC user but It seems your env has some issues with openmp...

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found was [here](https://blog.csdn.net/Jimmyzqb/article/details/83017650).

Check your `anaconda/lib` folder, `ll lib*omp*`, do you see some old `libiomp5.dylib` file? Remove it.

On mac, you can get the latest `libomp` by running `brew install libomp`.

Comment: `cd ~/opt/anaconda3/lib` and `ls libio*` to find these archives

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have 'Inf' values in the data. This is often the case when using `pct_change()`. xgBoost crashes the kernel when using Inf values.